# Tutorials for Raster Processing in PostGRES

Tags: raster, postgresql

I am looking to learn how to process rasters in PG. I am looking for the complete idiots guide to. Looking into how to attack this I get lost down many rabbit holes that I cannot get out of. Is there a comprehensive tutorial that you might recommend that will teach me about callbackfunc's, window functions, and other need to know basics of advanced raster processing in PG?

I have found no tutorials online thus far. The best learning I have had on this topic to date is by following through the pieces of ST_MapAlgebra but true understanding of what it describes (after following down all the rabbit holes) is missing for me.

Comment: Make a web search about Postgis raster, read some relevant documents and come back with more focused questions.

Comment: What's not focused about requesting help finding a tutorial on raster processing in PG? I have done lots of googling rasters in PG and end up with too many questions on too many different things to figure out a process. So, I was hoping to find someone that has had to start from scratch with rasters and help me build a solid understanding of what is involved. I

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that you were after tutorials while I was looking at your list of functionalities. Please edit the title of the question and list also a few of the best tutorials that you have found so far and others can improve the list.

Comment: completely reasonable question: "I am looking for the complete idiots guide to" just clean up your question a bit and you're good